# What does 三次職 mean?

Tags: phrases

Maybe this can provide more context "人間が三次職になる時と同じように", I can't figure out what this word means at all

Comment: What is the rest of the context? Not just the sentence, but where you saw it, who said it, the surrounding content etc.

Comment: The character is comparing the growth of spirits with the 三次職 of humans.


本来であれば、高位精霊が精霊王になるには、人間が三次職になる時と同じように、神の試練をクリアする必要がある。

Comment: Thank you for the full sentence, but the other information I mentioned would still be useful.

Comment: I saw it in a novel that I'm currently reading in Japanese, the main character was talking about the spirits in his world, and how they grow, and he likened their growth with the 三次職 of humans

Comment: I suppose it's this? https://ncode.syosetu.com/n1563fd/90/ This is information people can use to better answer the question.

Comment: Oh yeah you are right, this is the novel I'm reading, sorry for not giving you enough information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3次職 is "third-class jobs", "tier 3 job classes", "rank 3 jobs" or something like this. Typically, it is a kind of job a character can choose after mastering some 2次職 or 上級職 (advanced job), and you often have to clear some 試練-like event before actually upgrading your job. [Ragnarok Online](http://renewal.playragnarok.com/gameguide/classes_index.aspx) is probably one of the first games that popularized the term 3次職, but many games have similar systems with varying names.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I just noticed Ragnarok Online is planning to introduce even [4次職](https://www.onlinegamer.jp/news/202101190001/) :D

Comment: I hope balancing issues don't occur because of this